# VMware Workstation Running Ubuntu Freezes Frequently

Tags: vmware

I hope you can help me with an issue I've encountered recently.

Setup:

```
VM Software: VMware Workstation 17.5
Guest OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2
Host OS: Windows 11 22H2
Hardware: Intel CPU, NVIDIA GPU
```

Background:
Everything was working fine until a few days ago.

The Problem:
Recently, my Ubuntu VM started freezing intermittently. Here's what happens:

- I can move the cursor, but clicking anywhere doesn't have any effect.
- The keyboard becomes unresponsive and its lights turn off.
- Animations inside the VM, such as window movements and the clock updating, remain functional.
- I can still use CTRL + ALT to switch back to the host, which continues to work normally.
- In rare cases, if I wait for a while, the VM becomes responsive again. However, in most instances, I have to restart it. After a restart, it works fine for a bit but eventually runs into the same problem.

What I've Tried:

- I've searched various forums and tried suggestions such as enabling the enhanced keyboard feature, but it didn't help.
- I attempted to create a new VM from scratch, yet the issue persists.
- I've ensured that the VM has ample memory and threads allocated.

I'm not very knowledgeable about Ubuntu or VMs in general. Can someone guide me on how to solve this problem? What additional information do you need from me to assist further?

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: What is the host system's specs, and what specs did you assign to the VM?

Comment: The host is configured with i9-13900HX 24 cores, 32GB RAM.
The VM is configured with 16 GB RAM, 2 processors with 4 cores per processor, and 180 GB SCSI hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the bottom of your VM's vmx file:

```
keyboard.allowBothIRQs = "FALSE"
keyboard.vusb.enable = "TRUE"
```

this fixed it for me.

Comment: Can you please explain why that helped you? What kind of keyboard are you using?